# How to remove a part of a string which will always be at the last?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I made a function that removes the last part of the string which will always start from `_` and get the integer, but all I get is the text part and not the integer

How can this be achieved?

```js
function splitLast(arg) {
  if (arg.includes(".") && arg.includes("_")) {
    return parseFloat(arg.split("_").pop())
  } else if (arg.includes(".") != true && arg.includes("_")) {
    return parseInt(+arg.split("_").pop())
  } else {
    throw "Arguments passed does not contain the valid result characters or isnt a required Datatype for thefunction"
  }
}

console.log(splitLast("22_no"), 'should be 22')
console.log(splitLast("22.1_no"), 'should be 22.1')
```

Comment: You say the string "starts from  \_" and you want to "get the integer", but in your own sample code the text after "_" is "no", which is not an integer.

Comment: Also your code should be posted here as **text**, not an image.

Comment: The last part i.e the string is divided into two parts first being the integer the second being the text one , so the text one will always start with _ and then everything as text after it

Comment: `"22.1_no".split("_").pop()` will return the the string "no". `"22.1_no".split("_")` returns the array `["22.1", "no"]`.

Comment: So is it like return parseInt(arg[0])

Comment: No, `.pop()` gives you the **last** element of the array, not the first.

Comment: "22.1_no".split("_") should give the array ["22.1" , "no"] , so i might be able to get it by -  return arg[0] right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD: A better solution

You can use `parseFloat()` function without additional checks and string parsing (it will do it all for you):

```js
function splitLast(arg) {
  if (isNaN(arg.trim()[0])) {
    throw new Error('argument is not valid')
  }

  return parseFloat(arg)
}

console.log(splitLast("22_no"), 'should be 22')
console.log(splitLast("22.1_no"), 'should be 22.1')
console.log(splitLast("a22.1_no"), 'should throw')
console.log(splitLast("  a22.1_no"), 'should throw')
```

`isNaN()` check is needed because [`parseFloat(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) returns:

1. A floating-point number parsed from the given string (which is exactly what you need)
2. NaN when the first non-whitespace character cannot be converted to a number (which is an edge-case but we should know about it)

---

Old solution:

Probably, you have to use the `shift()` method instead of `pop()`.

---

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element. This method changes the length of the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

---

```js
function splitLast(arg) {
  if (arg.includes(".") && arg.includes("_")) {
    return parseFloat(arg.split("_").shift())
  } else if (arg.includes(".") != true && arg.includes("_")) {
    return parseInt(arg.split("_").shift())
  } else {
    throw "Arguments passed does not contain the valid result characters or isnt a required Datatype for thefunction"
  }
}

console.log(splitLast("22_no"), 'should be 22')
console.log(splitLast("22.1_no"), 'should be 22.1')
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regexp and `.replace`:

```js
function splitLast(value) {
  return value.replace(/_.*$/, '');
}

console.log(splitLast("22_no"), 'should be 22')
console.log(splitLast("22.1_no"), 'should be 22.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to remove text from string and only numbers with underscore remains.

```
 var ret = "22.1_no";
    var str = ret.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
    console.log("_"+str);
```